Needed support for "Configure backup on virtual machines with a given tag..." policy not supporting SQL *-WS2022 O.S. version
Azure built-in Policy "Configure backup on virtual machines with a given tag to an existing recovery services vault in the same location" doesn't support SQL *-WS2022 O.S. version.
Evaluation condition is the following actually
  {
    "anyOf": [
    {
       "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
       "like": "*-WS2019"
    },
    {
      "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
      "like": "*-WS2016"
    },
    {
     "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
     "like": "*-WS2016-BYOL"
    },
    {
       "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
       "like": "*-WS2012R2"
    },
    {
       "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
       "like": "*-WS2012R2-BYOL"
    }
    ]
  }

I know i can create a custom policy and add the support of the new O.S. version.
But the question from the customer is:

where i can get a roadmap of the Azure built-in policies planned updates?
is there a way to know when the built-in policy will be updated? Apart of opening a customer support ticket i mean.

expecting info about where to gather Azure policies roadmap

Did you mean Azure Policy Updates? If yes, you can get it from this Official Site

You can raise a support request to add a new operating system version to the built-in policy. In the meantime, you can create a custom policy to include the operating system. For Azure Policy updates, you can refer to the link : https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/675ae472-f324-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

thank you @JashuaCriss, for the update i'm looking for a roadmap: future planned updates, not the actual releases history


where i can get a roadmap of the Azure built-in policies planned updates?

I hope this is the only site for the Azure Updates or roadmap on all categories based on my experience.
As I can see in one of the Tech Community MS article, they have mentioned whatever the key features and services that are published as updated with these 3 statuses: launched, in development and in preview.

If you want updates on specific category such as Azure Policy, you can filter by Product Category on the given dropdown or search with that tag or keyword to get the relevant information:



If you want immediate updates, you can subscribe to Azure Roadmap also
